# Yii2 CRUD: How to implement Cancel button

Tags: yii2, crud, cancel-button

I'm just learning Yii 2 framework. I'm curios what is the best practice to implement Cancel button in Create/Update form of typical CRUD application. I generated CRUD application from the Yii 2.0. tutorial https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-gii. Then I added Cancel button in _form.php view

```
<div class="country-form">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'code')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'population')->textInput() ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Cancel'), ['name' => 'cancel', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

And modified actionUpdate method of CountryController:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    $request = Yii::$app->request;



    if(null !==(Yii::$app->request->post('cancel'))) {
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }


    if ($model->load($request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        //return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->code]);
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }



    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

It works, but I stuck with the validation. I want to skip validation when the user presses Cancel button.

Comment: cancel should normally clear the form, or reset the form, you can use the `Html::resetButton()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To cancel you need to use a link

```
<?= Html::a('Cancel', ['/controller/action'], ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

However to reset, you can use a button

```
<?= Html::resetButton('Reset', ['class' => 'reset']) ?>
```

Please refer this doc to see how you can customize it https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-html

Comment: OK, it's clear with Cancel button. But if I want to have 'Save Draft' button: POST without validation?

Answer (score 3):

You are using submit button for cancel. Thats why form is validating.
Use normal button instead on Submit button.

Replace this line

```
<?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Cancel'), ['name' => 'cancel', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

With

```
<?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Cancel'), ['index'], ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

could be you are looking for the reset button

```
 echo Html::resetButton('Reset', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']);
```